# Get object instances for a class

Tags: netbeans

I have an instance file register for a custom MultiDataObject in System FileSystem entry: Loaders/text/custom-mime-type/Factories.

My application creates this objects when I open a project and my LogicalView creates the nodes for files in that project.

I need to get a list of instances for those MultiDataObject type, but I've not found way to achieve this.

I try to get this using Lookups.forPath, but anything returned.

¿Any clue for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

With some reflection magic you can get them from a DataObjectPool - package private class in Data Loaders module (see `openide.loaders/src/org/openide/loaders/DataObjectPool.java` in NetBeans sources). There is no official API of this kind. Intentionally.

I'd say there is something wrong if you need this information. Perhaps you would get better advice if you had explained better what you want to achieve. Asking at [NetBeans forum / mailing list](https://netbeans.org/community/lists/index.html) will increase your chances even higher.

Comment: As you say, it's possible that I am doing something wrong...I'm newbee with Netbeans, but actually I don't know how to get some information from it. The reason that I am asking this, is I need from module A to get all instances from objects created in module B, to fill in a JList. I will very gratefull if you guide me how to achive this, or best, the concepts to know why this way to work with NB is wrong. Also I posted this question in NB forum, but for now anybody answered it.